# In how many ways can the entire set "AAAABCDEFGHIJK" be arranged so that the A's are separated by a gap of at least 2 spaces?

Tags: combinatorics

In solving this problem, I think I have essentially derived the form for "n" spaces, but I'd like to verify that this is a correct approach, since I am just a high school student and it's possible I'm incorrect:

We can consider the A's to be |'s and the other letters to be x's (I'm setting it up for stars and bars visually). Given that we have to arrange the A's with 2 spaces in between each, we must have a base form of |xx|xx|xx|. Now, we have to arrange, among the dividers (the A's), 4 more x's for the total of 10, since 6 are already fixed between the A's. This turns into stars and bars with 4 bars and 4 stars = C(8,4). But we must also account for the distinguishability of the x's (BCDEFGHIJK), and since all are distinct there is no need for permutation with repetition and thus there are 10! ways to order the placement of the letters in each arrangement we have made prior. Thus, the answer to this particular question is C(8,4)*10!

Is this correct? I believe it accounts both for the different distributions of gaps (C(8,4)) and the placement of distinguishable letters in those gaps (10!).

Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me, and well explained too.